# $\frac{n!}{(n+\frac{1}{x})!} = ?$ for some positive real $x$

Tags: real-analysis, factorial

Is there a simple way to express : $\frac{n!}{(n+\frac{1}{x})!} = ?$ where $x, n$ are positive real numbers ?

Comment: $m!$ is not defined for real numbers, it is defined for natural numbers. You want the gamma function.

Comment: Ok, but then is it possible to express this fraction using the gamma function ?

Comment: I was wondering about using Stirling factorial approximation...

Comment: If you are looking for big values of $n$ Stirling can be good.

Comment: Yes actually I am trying to find the limit of this ratio when $n$ tends to infinity... Yet I was wondering, If $x$ is just a real number does the ratio above tends to $0$ when $n$ tends to infinty ?

Comment: @J.OK the limit is zero for $x>0$ because $$\frac{n!}{(n+1/x)\Gamma(n+1/x)}=\frac{n!}{(n+1/x)^{\underline n}\Gamma(1+1/x)}\le\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k+1/x}$$

Comment: Nicely done ! Yet how can you say that : $\displaystyle\prod_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k+1/x} = 0$ ?

Comment: Take logarithms in the RHS of the above inequality and use integral test.

Comment: @J.OK because multiplying any two numbers in $(0,1)$ results in a number less than either of them. As we multiply more and more numbers, our result shrinks more and more. Simple squeezing shows us that this must reach $0$

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for is found in the identity

$$\frac{\Gamma(n+x)}{\Gamma(n)}=(x)_n$$

where $(x)_n$ is the Pochhammer polynomial.

Ref: K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, Springer.

Comment: Thank you, then the answer to my question is : $\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x})_n}$ ? And do you know if there is a way to calculate : $\lim n \rightarrow + \infty \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x})_n}$ ?

Comment: Just looking at your original equation I would expect that it should be something shy of unity (1), but I can't imagine how to do that off the top my head. The problem is that as $n$ increases so does the number of terms in the the polynomial. And by the way, I almost fell into the trap $\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x})_n}=(x)_n$, IT IS NOT!

Comment: OK, here's what you need, the asymptotic expansion for the gamma function is derived from *Stirling's formula*, $\Gamma(x)\sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{x}}e^{-x}x^x(1+\mathcal{O}\frac{1}{x}),\ \ x\to\infty$. Is this enough to get you started?

Comment: Nice ! I am going to try using the asymptotic expansion and hopefully I am going to get something.

Answer (score 0):

$n!\sim\sqrt{2n\pi}\cdot(\frac{n}{e})^n$.

$\left(n+{1\over x}\right )!\sim\sqrt{2\left(n+{1\over x}\right ) \pi}\cdot\left (\frac{\left(n+{1\over x}\right ) }{e}\right )^\left(n+{1\over x}\right ) $.

$\frac{n!}{\left(n+{1\over x}\right )!} \sim \frac{e^{1 \over x}}{\sqrt{\left(1+{1\over nx}\right )}}  \frac{1}{n^{1\over x}}\frac{1}{\left(1+{1\over nx}\right )^{1\over x}}  \frac{1}{\left(1+{1\over nx}\right )^n} $

$\frac{n!}{\left(n+{1\over x}\right )!} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+{1\over nx}\right )}}  \frac{1}{\left(n+{1\over x}\right )^{1\over x}}  $